# Moodle course enrollment

Tags: moodle

Is this the correct way of enrolling user to a course.

```
$context = get_context_instance(CONTEXT_COURSE, $courseid);     
$roleid = 9;
is_enrolled($context, $USER->id, $roleid);

enrol_try_internal_enrol($courseid, $USER->id, $roleid );
```

When I execute,  say 5 courses at a time, it sometimes enrol 3 courses out of 5 and enrol other category courses too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `enrol_try_internal_enrol` will do what you want but it only uses the `manual` enrolment method. To use a different enrolment method or for more control:

```
// Depends on the enrolment method you want to use.
// This uses the standard manual enrolment.
if (!enrol_is_enabled('manual')) {
    // Manual enrolment not enabled at the site level.
    debugging('Manual enrolment is not enabled', DEBUG_DEVELOPER);
    return false;
}

// Get the manual enrol plugin.
if (!$enrolplugin = enrol_get_plugin('manual')) {
    // Might not be installed.
    debugging('Manual enrolment is not available', DEBUG_DEVELOPER);
    return false;
}

// Marker to check if the user was enrolled.
$enrolled = false;

// Look for the manual enrolment instance in this course.
// It might not be enabled at the course level.
$instances = enrol_get_instances($courseid, true);
foreach ($instances as $instance) {
    if ($instance->enrol === 'manual') {
        // Enrol user.
        $enrolplugin->enrol_user($instance, $userid, $roleid);

        $enrolled = true;

        break;
    }
}

if (!$enrolled) {
    debugging('No manual enrol plugin for course id : ' . $courseid, DEBUG_DEVELOPER);
    return false;
}
```